# Next js context resolverUrl

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

When i try to get URL in server side
`const { resolverUrl } = context`
I receive URL with '+' characters change to '%20'

Is there any solution to receive URL without this change in server side

Answer (score 0):

It's encoded - just decode it using [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)

```
const resolverUrl = decodeURI(context.resolverUrl)
```